# Returning Null for the Related Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I am using EF core 2.1.14
Here is my Class for DbContext which I have created by scaffolding:

```
public partial class AgriDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AgriDbContext()
    {
    }

    public AgriDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(GetOptions(connectionString))
    {
    }
    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options;
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AgroItem> AgroItems { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFav> BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFavs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BuyersAddAgroItemToInterest> BuyersAddAgroItemToInterests { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SellersFavoritesBuyer> SellersFavoritesBuyers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.0-rtm-35687");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Advertisement>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Picture).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.City)
                .WithMany(p => p.Advertisements)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("ADVERTISEMENTS_INCLUDE_A_CITY");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Item)
                .WithMany(p => p.Advertisements)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ItemId)
                .HasConstraintName("AN_ADVERTISEMENT_IS_RELATED_TO_AN_ITEM");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Seller)
                .WithMany(p => p.Advertisements)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SellerId)
                .HasConstraintName("USERS_POST_ADVERTISEMENTS");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<AgroItem>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Uname).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Category)
                .WithMany(p => p.AgroItems)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("AGRO_ITEMS_BELONG_TO_A_CATEGORY");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFav>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.BuyerId, e.AdId });

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Ad)
                .WithMany(p => p.BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFavs)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AdId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_BUYER_ADDS_DIFFERENT_ADS_TO_FAV_ADVERTISEMENTS");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Buyer)
                .WithMany(p => p.BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFavs)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BuyerId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_BUYER_ADDS_DIFFERENT_ADS_TO_FAV_USERS");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<BuyersAddAgroItemToInterest>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.BuyerId, e.ItemId });

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Buyer)
                .WithMany(p => p.BuyersAddAgroItemToInterests)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BuyerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_BUYERS_ADD_AGRO_ITEM_TO_INTEREST_USERS");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Item)
                .WithMany(p => p.BuyersAddAgroItemToInterests)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ItemId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_BUYERS_ADD_AGRO_ITEM_TO_INTEREST_AGRO_ITEMS");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Uname).IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
                .HasName("UNIQUE_LOCATION")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SellersFavoritesBuyer>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.SellerId, e.BuyerId });

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Buyer)
                .WithMany(p => p.SellersFavoritesBuyerBuyers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BuyerId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_SELLERS_FAVORITES_BUYERS_USERS1");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Seller)
                .WithMany(p => p.SellersFavoritesBuyerSellers)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SellerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_SELLERS_FAVORITES_BUYERS_USERS");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.CcompanyCode, e.CcountryCode, e.Cphone })
                .HasName("UNIQUE_CONTACT")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.Address).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Fname).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Lname).IsUnicode(false);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.City)
                .WithMany(p => p.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CityId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_USERS_CITIES");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

In the above code CityId is properly Related as a foreign Key and there is also a property for City in the User class. But whenever I get a user it returns null in the City Property but it returns CityId from the database.

Below is my Entity Model Class

```
[Table("USERS")]
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Advertisements = new HashSet<Advertisement>();
        BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFavs = new HashSet<BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFav>();
        BuyersAddAgroItemToInterests = new HashSet<BuyersAddAgroItemToInterest>();
        SellersFavoritesBuyerBuyers = new HashSet<SellersFavoritesBuyer>();
        SellersFavoritesBuyerSellers = new HashSet<SellersFavoritesBuyer>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("FName")]
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("LName")]
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("CCompanyCode")]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string CcompanyCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("CCountryCode")]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string CcountryCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("CPhone")]
    [StringLength(7)]
    public string Cphone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Column("GLat", TypeName = "decimal(10, 8)")]
    public decimal? Glat { get; set; }
    [Column("GLng", TypeName = "decimal(11, 8)")]
    public decimal? Glng { get; set; }
    public bool BuyerFlag { get; set; }
    public bool SellerFlag { get; set; }
    public short CityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Seller")]
    public virtual ICollection<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Buyer")]
    public virtual ICollection<BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFav> BuyerAddsDifferentAdsToFavs { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Buyer")]
    public virtual ICollection<BuyersAddAgroItemToInterest> BuyersAddAgroItemToInterests { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Buyer")]
    public virtual ICollection<SellersFavoritesBuyer> SellersFavoritesBuyerBuyers { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Seller")]
    public virtual ICollection<SellersFavoritesBuyer> SellersFavoritesBuyerSellers { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this method of repository to get the user

```
public EFarmer.Models.User GetUser(ContactNumberFormat contact)
{
    var user = users
        .Where(x => x.CcountryCode == contact.CountryCode
        && x.CcompanyCode == contact.CompanyCode
        && x.Cphone == contact.PhoneNumber).First() ?? null;
    return (user != null) ? new EFarmer.Models.User
    {
        Address = user.Address,
        City = EFarmer.Models.City.Convert(user.City),
        ContactNumber = new ContactNumberFormat(user.CcountryCode, user.CcompanyCode, user.Cphone),
        IsBuyer = user.BuyerFlag,
        IsSeller = user.SellerFlag,
        Location = new GeoLocation { Latitude = user.Glat, Longitude = user.Glng },
        Name = new NameFormat { FirstName = user.Fname, LastName = user.Lname },
        Id = user.Id
    } : null;
}
```

And here is the convert method which converts Entity model to my Business Model, it give null reference exception due to null in City from entity model

```
public static City Convert(EFarmerPkModelLibrary.Entities.City city)
{
    return new City
    {
        GeoLocation = new GeoLocation { Latitude = city.Glat, Longitude = city.Glng },
        Id = city.Id,
        Name = city.Name
    };
}
```

Comment: EF Core documentation - [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from your example and tags (EF Core 2.1) the issue likely is that lazy loading hasn't been enabled. Check that you've added the dependency for the EF Core Proxies and added `optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();` to the DbContext `OnModelConfiguring` override.

A recommendation though is not to roll your own mappers such as the static Convert method, and instead look to leverage an existing mapper like AutoMapper. A key feature of Automapper for integrating with EF is Projection (`ProjectTo`). This can build your DTOs/ViewModels as part of the Linq expression that is fed to the database resulting in far, far more efficient queries and no multi-hits from things like lazy loading.

With Lazy loading you will have 1 query hit to get all fields from your user, then 1 query hit to get all fields from your City, plus 1 hit for each and every other lazy-load call. If you are doing something like fetching a list of users, you would have 1 hit to get the list of users, but then 1 hit for each city for each user!

With eager loading you would have 1 query hit to get all fields from your user and their related city, which is a lower performance hit. However it is still fetching *all* fields, whether your DTO/ViewModel needs them or not. There is also the risk of forgetting to explicitly eager load related data in queries, especially when expanding entities to add new relationships, which ends up reverting to the lazy load performance penalties or issues.

With Automapper's `ProjectTo`, you would have 1 query hit to get only the fields from User, City, and any other related entities which the DTO/ViewModel requested. No need to remember to `Include` relatives, or worry about lazy load hits. Clean, efficient, and future proof.